# Suggested pattern for gracefully restart cancelled async Tasks on non UI application

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have a console app that instantiates a WeatherClientManager class.
The main thread in the console app requests current weather status in the WeatherClientManager class, but the WeatherClientManager class continuously receives data from a server. 
In code:

```
 public static void Main(string [])
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        Task.Run(()=>p.RunLoop());


    }

    class Program{


        WeatherClientManager wcM; 
        public void RunLoop()
        {

            wcM = new WeatherClientManager ();
            await wcM.InitiateConnection().ConfigureAwait(false);

        }
    }

    class WeatherClientManager 
    {
        public async Task<bool> InitiateConnection()
        {
            TCPClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(GetTCPDetailsFromConfig())

            await tcpClient.ConnectAsync()

            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            if(tcpClient.Connected)
            {
               Task.Run(()=>ReceiveTask(cts.Token));
               Task.Run(()=>SendKeepAlive(cts.Token));
               return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void ReceiveTask(CancellationToken t)
        {
            try{
                networkStream.Receive(..) // throws exception
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
               Stop(e);
            }
        }


        private void SendKeepAlive(CancellationToken t)
       {
            while(!t.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try{
                    networkStream.Write(..) // throws exception
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                   Stop(e);
                }
            }
       }

       private void Stop(Exception e )
       {
         log.Error(e);
         e.Cancel();

       }
    }
```

One of many crap ideas I have is:

```
 Task.Run( () =>
    {
          while(true)
          {
              var t1 = Task.Run(()=>ReceiveTask(cts.Token));
              var t2= Task.Run(()=>SendKeepAlive(cts.Token));

              try{
                Tasks.WhenAny(); // should block
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {

              }
              finally{
                Cleanup();
                InitiateConnections();
              }

          }
    }
```

But I hate the idea of spinning a task to control two sub tasks. My problem is where and how to re-initiate the connection. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I've updated the code such that WeatherClientManager has a OnDisconnectDetected event. So the Program.cs class subscribes like so:

```
weatherServerManager.OnDisconnectDetected += HandleDisconnectDetection

public async void HandleDisconnectDetection()
{
    wsM = new WeatherClientManager ();
    wsM.InitiateConnection().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

 private void SendKeepAlive(CancellationToken t)
 {
     while (...)
     {
         try{}
         catch(Exception e)
         {
           OnDisconnectDetected?.Invoke();
         }
     }
}
```

When the handler is invoked by the WeatherClientManager it creates a new task that should continue in a different context. The KeepAlive task should exit then.

Still feels hacky but ideas welcome!

Comment: check Polly (https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki)

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Which part specifically?

Comment: Retry - https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry

Comment: OK thanks. For the purposes of learning I'd like a non library solution though :)

Comment: Welcome, check out their code for the same, it will be a non library solution :)

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was downvoted or suggested close. I don't care about the differing opinions. I just want ideas better than mine

Comment: Just to take care of such random folks I have to up vote various questions and answers. Down voting everything is very bad, it doesn't allow people learn anything. Mindless fold I must say

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Appreciate that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, I prefer composition of methods over raising events. In particular, avoid the `Task.Run`-based fire-and-forget.

In the case of asynchronous sockets, I think it makes sense to give each socket a main loop:

```
class WeatherClientManager
{
  public async Task MainLoop()
  {
    TCPClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(GetTCPDetailsFromConfig())
    await tcpClient.ConnectAsync();

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var receiveTask = Task.Run(()=>ReceiveTask(cts.Token));
    var keepaliveTask = Task.Run(()=>SendKeepAlive(cts.Token));
    await Task.WhenAll(receiveTask, keepaliveTask);
  }
}
```

These can then be composed into the main program's main loop:

```
class Program
{
  public async Task RunLoop()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      wcM = new WeatherClientManager();
      await wcM.MainLoop();
    }
  }
}
```

which in turn is composed into `Main`:

```
public static void Main(string [])
{
  Program p = new Program();
  p.RunLoop().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

By avoiding fire-and-forget, you're ensuring that your code will always observe all exceptions. Ignoring tasks is occasionally okay but usually a mistake.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I *was* hoping you would answer. Thanks :)
I'm having a bit of a trouble following the control flow of RunLoop. Does `await wcM.MainLoop()` exit out of the while block?

So if I had:
`p.RunLoop()`
`p.DoSomethingElse()` would `DoSomethingElse()` execute? 
However, I believe you've given me an idea on how to proceed. Will try when I get home :)

Comment: `MainLoop` completes when `ReceiveTask` and `SendKeepAlive` are complete (i.e., the socket is closed). `RunLoop` should never complete unless there is an unexpected exception.

Comment: Thanks for that Stephen. Do you have a blog on the state machine generated by async await?

Comment: @LewsTherin: No; I don't think it's necessary to learn `async`. I have [an async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) instead. If you want the state machine details, [see Jon Skeet's eduasync](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/eduasync/).